# How to show Dynamically LISTVIEW with JSON & AsyncTask?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am having trouble to view my YouTube JSON data in LIST-VIEW.when I run the following code it runs but my app have a blank page & then app is shutting DOWN.By the way i am beginner in JSON parsing & YOUTUBE API.
In this code i just have a JSON DATA using YouTube DATA API & I want to Show all DATA(TITLE,DESCRIPTION & THUMBNAIL) in a List View.

Here is my MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ListView listview;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
static String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResult=30&q=natok+bangla+mosharrof+karim&key=AIzaSyCR40QlsuX0aFfBV-wEPDsH_jxna1tDFRA";

static String VIDEO_ID = "videoId";
static String TITLE = "title";
static String DESCRIPTION = "description";
//static String FLAG = "flag";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    new DownloadJSON().execute();
}

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResult=30&q=natok+bangla&key=AIzaSyCR40QlsuX0aFfBV-wEPDsH_jxna1tDFRA");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("items");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("videoId", jsonobject.getString("videoId"));
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
                map.put("description", jsonobject.getString("description"));
               // map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("flag"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

here is my adapter code

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView rank;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;
    ImageView flag;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
    country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
    population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);

    // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
    flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    rank.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.VIDEO_ID));
    country.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.TITLE));
    population.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.DESCRIPTION));
    // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
    // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
  //  imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG), flag);
    // Capture ListView item click
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Get the position
            resultp = data.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
            // Pass all data rank
            intent.putExtra("videoId", resultp.get(MainActivity.VIDEO_ID));
            // Pass all data country
            intent.putExtra("title", resultp.get(MainActivity.TITLE));
            // Pass all data population
            intent.putExtra("description",resultp.get(MainActivity.DESCRIPTION));
            // Pass all data flag
        //    intent.putExtra("flag", resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG));
            // Start SingleItemView Class
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    return itemView;
}
```

}

& LogCat error is..

12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime: Process: amit.jsonparsewithimage, PID: 17237
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:     at amit.jsonparsewithimage.MainActivity$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:     at amit.jsonparsewithimage.MainActivity$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:42)
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-01 08:47:27.420 17237-17258/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

**JSONFUNCTION.java** here is the code..

```
public class JSONfunctions {

public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    // Download JSON data from URL
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // Convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

}

And the MANIFEST code is..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SingleItemView" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What is your Logcat output on the crash?

Comment: post your adapter code and log

Comment: I Updated my question with adapter & log.

Comment: you get a NPE, i guest that "jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResult=30&q=natok+bangla&key=AIzaSyCR40QlsuX0aFfBV-wEPDsH_jxna1tDFRA");" jsonobject is NULL

Comment: Could you provide AndroidMainfest.xml file and JSONfunctions class

Comment: I edited my all question....

Comment: @HoangNguyen can u solve this??

Comment: your parsing is wrong. from "items" you need to get  JSONObject called "id" from that  you should get videoId. And another JSONObject called "snippet" from items and Title etc from that.

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu can u please descrive the whole answer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using HTTPPost when you are trying to get values from JSON?

It should be

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
```

And the parsing is wrong , from "items" you need to get JSONObject called "id" from that you should get videoId. And another JSONObject called "snippet" from items and Title etc from that.

```
JSONArray jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("items");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    // Retrive JSON Objects
    JSONObject jsonObjId = jsonobject.getJSONObject("id");
    map.put("videoId", jsonObjId.getString("videoId"));

    JSONObject jsonObjSnippet = jsonobject.getJSONObject("snippet");
    map.put("title", jsonObjSnippet.getString("title"));
    map.put("description", jsonObjSnippet.getString("description"));
    // map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("flag"));
    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
    arraylist.add(map);
}
```

Comment: I cant understand your answer...can u please describe the whole answer & where i can make changes?

Comment: Replace HTTPPost to HTTPGet in JSONfunctions.java. and replace the above code in Mainactivity doingbackground JSON parse inside try block

Comment: one thing how can i get image from json?

Comment: search for Imageloaders from url in android

Comment: try UniversalImageLoader or piccaso or GLide and if you get stuck post the code you tried in a new post will be glad to help.